# Loop to compare numbers within file name

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So I've written a code to compare if a certain number within the file name is bigger than 11 and if it is than it should make a directory.

```
-->Mainfolder
   -->Jan
      -->Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jonas.De Preter.s.ua_poging_2019-11-12
   -->Feremans
      -->Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Len.Feremans.s.ua_poging_2019-11-10
   ...
```

The code needs to get the day of the provided date
and if it's above 11 it creates a directory "late_inzending"
So it should look like this

```
-->Mainfolder
   -->Jan
      -->Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jonas.De Preter.s.ua_poging_2019-11-12
      -->late_inzending
   ...
```

My code doesn't seem to work

```
for dir in */
do
    cut1=$(echo "$dir" | cut -f4 -d '_')
    cut2=$(echo "$cut1" | cut -f3 -d '-')
    declare -i x="$cut2"
    declare -i y=11
    if (( x > y))
    then
        mkdir late_inzending
    fi    
done
```

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't seem to work"?  Also, from what location are you executing your code?  Mainfolder, Jan, etc...?

Comment: By "doesn't seem to work" I mean that the script does nothing. And I'm running the code from the the main folder

Comment: It does create a directory, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: When i run the code it doens't create the needed directory. Could it be because some filenames have a whitespace in them ?

Comment: I don't see a problem either. Have you tried printing $x before the if command? Does it always hold the value it is supposed to be holding?

Comment: `cut1` is empty. You're asking for the fifth field delimited with an `_`, but there are only four fields.

Comment: Your loop is only getting the 'Jan', 'Feremans' directories and not the files in those directories so per @tink your `cut1` is empty and your `if` check will fail so the `mkdir` is never executed.

Comment: I've update my code and changed the empty cut. How do I make it check the files within the Jan and Feremans directory ?

Comment: One option might be to use `find` and change your loop to some thing like `while read -r file ; do <<parse day from file here and make dir if needed>>  ; done < <(find . -type f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in ./*/*/; do                   #: From main plus one level down
  [[ ! -d "$d" ]] && continue         #: If it is not a directory, skip it.
  end="${d##*-}"                      #: To remain only the last 2 strings and a /, e.g. 12/
  (( ${end%/} > 11 )) &&              #: Remove the trailing `/`, to remain only 12 and compare.
  echo mkdir -p "$d"late_inzending    #: Append the desired string to the directory and create it.
done
```

---

- Execute from within `main`
- Remove the `echo` if you're ok with the ouput.

---

Resources for the answer above

- [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html)
- [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)
- `help test`